# Anaconda navigator and activate.bat issues with whitespace in Windows

Tags: python, windows, cmd, anaconda, prompt

Very recently, I suddenly started having problems with the Anaconda prompt and launching jupyter instances with VS Code. There is an Access Denied error, but even as administrator I am getting an error that point me towards some issue with whitespaces in my path. I have never had this issue and anaconda was working for well over a year now.

So, I uninstalled Anaconda and re-installed it completely. Still the error persists when I launch from the start menu.

```
Access is denied.
The system cannot find the file C:\Users\Ananth.
Could Not Find C:\Users\Ananth Mahadevan\AppData\Local\Temp\conda-16154.tmp

C:\Users\Ananth Mahadevan>
```

So when I run cmd.exe in admin mode and navigate to Anaconda3\Scripts and run activate.bat I still get this

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts>activate.bat
Not a conda environment: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\Mahadevan\AppData\Local\Temp\conda-22297.tmp
```

Then I tried to activate the base specifically and get this error

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts>conda activate base
activate does not accept more than one argument:
['base', 'Mahadevan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\conda-1957.tmp']
```

This error lead me to https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6704, but this seems like an old issue and looks to be closed. I tested this by running the PowerShell Anaconda prompt, and there activate.bat works fine.

The issue seems to be with the `Scripts\activate.bat` which calls `condabin\conda.bat` in turn `condabin\_conda_activate.bat` where I can see the code that creates a unique temp path and tries to locate it

```
@REM This method will not work if %TMP% contains any spaces.
:tmpName
@SET UNIQUE=%TMP%\conda-%RANDOM%.tmp
@IF EXIST "%UNIQUE%" goto :tmpName
@"%CONDA_EXE%" %_CE_M% %_CE_CONDA% shell.cmd.exe %* 1>%UNIQUE%
```

It clearly says this will not work if temp has any spaces. I think I found the issue, but not the solution. It is also strange as Anaconda was working perfectly well, and the last thing I can remember was the new windows updates, which has got me to suspect it.

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution at https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8510. There is an issue with whitespace in temp folders. The fix was to change TEMP and TMP environment variables to a location without whitespaces like `c:\conda_tmp`. It works fine after this fix.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Anaconda, Inc. | "ERROR: Cannot install into directo...](https://support.anaconda.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2913013-%22error-cannot-install-into-directories-with-spaces%22) , this issue has been fixed in version `5.0.1` of Anaconda installer.

A similar issue -- [Installation with spaces// Anaconda prompt stop responding after updating conda. · Issue #6704 · conda/conda](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6704) and linked [Problem with spaces in paths on windows · Issue #58 · ContinuumIO/menuinst](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/menuinst/issues/58) -- is claimed to be fixed in `5.1`.

Comment: That's not exactly the issue. If you see the outputs I have included, I have installed Anaconda in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3. The error occurs when the activate script tries to create a temporary file, which goes to C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local which has a whitespace and then causes problems. I also did download the newest installer from the Anaconda website and there were no issues while installing.

Comment: @AnanthMahadevan I can't readily see any other relevant issues and PRs in https://github.com/conda/conda/issues and https://github.com/conda/conda/pulls . Write your own then if you have an idea how to fix this.