# Windows + Conda (The system cannot find the path specified.)

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using Anaconda Navigator, and in turn conda to manage packages in Python.
Workflow: open Anaconda Navigator GUI> base(root) - Open Terminal

After open the the terminal it shows below error:

The system cannot find the path specified.
activate does not accept more than one argument:
['C:\Anaconda3', 'User\AppData\Local\Temp\conda-23186-18166.tmp']

Can anyone help me how to fix this problem.

**Your Environment**
Operating System: Windows 10
Python Version Used: 3.6
Environment Information: Conda

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anaconda navigator and activate.bat issues with whitespace in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55996021/anaconda-navigator-and-activate-bat-issues-with-whitespace-in-windows)